# VS 2013 CodeLens

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2013, codelens

When I open a project from the Visual Studio Team Services (scrum 3 template) I only get the **CodeLens** reference count. Is this a bug in VS? Why do I not have **CodeLens** with full **TFS versioning** Comments, Edited By, etc.?

***FYI:*** I have enabled all options in Visual Studio Tools > Options > **CodeLens**.

I also tried the following with no success:

- Create a new project in Visual Studio Team Services.
- Disable and re-enable **CodeLens**.

Comment: Are you running TFS 2013? There are new API's only available in TFS 2013 for CodeLens annotations.

Comment: No i using TFS Service (MS's cloud TFS - TFS 2013) and i founded that local TFS 2013 is required to have full codelens functionality in VS2013 (Clouded TFS is not support codelens for now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an update!

Currently CodeLens is being developed for Visual Studio Team Services, currently in Public Preview for what I have read so far, in US and West-Europe.

**Requirements:**

1. Be using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4, or Visual Studio 2015
   (Preview or later version).
2. Check your code into Team Foundation
   Version Control in Visual Studio Team Services.

Just updated to VS Ultimate Update 4, already had a solution setup on Visual Studio Team Services, works great as expected.

**troubleshoot, CodeLens not appearing?**

1. Close all Visual Studio Instances.
2. Remove the cache from %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services\5.0\
3. Reopen Visual Studio, open the solution from Visual Studio Team Services.

I'm not sure if it was necessary to do this for me, I did it, looked like it had no effect and the codeLens still didn't appear. While I was typing out a new question they suddenly appeared. So it could take a few minutes.

Source: [CodeLens in Visual Studio Team Services is now in public preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/03/11/codelens-in-visual-studio-online-is-now-in-public-preview-for-europe-region.aspx?utm_content=bufferb290a&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

**For Visual Studio 2015:** Should be available by default. [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/24/visual-studio-2015-and-codelens.aspx). I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and it works good, even more then in visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 3):

As DaveShaw answered, TFS 2013 is required, but I still had problems after installing TFS 2013.  Turns out you need to have CodeIndexing enabled on the TFS Server.  My codeindexing was on, but I think the index was corrupted somehow and I had to reindex it.

This is a good link (go to the Q&A section at the bottom):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn269218%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Here is the TFSConfig CodeIndex syntax:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn280925(v=vs.120).aspx

Once you get your codeindex running, you have to do a get latest from Visual Studio and then your codelens should work.

Comment: I know TFS is required but i did not know that MS's cloud TFS version builded on TFS 2013 is not support codelens yet..ty

Answer (score 2):

Server-side CodeLens indexing is not currently supported by the Visual Studio Team Services, only on-premises TFS. This is partly because of the potentially unbounded number of tenant accounts in the online service, each with its own background job to do the indexing of changesets. However this could change in the future.

Source: I worked on CodeLens.

Comment: Is it now? Or how can I enable it?

Comment: somehow my codelens only show -references. It works fine before.