# Visual Studio 2013 RC CodeLens not showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2013, codelens

I installed Visual Studio 2013 Release Candidate and after opening a project I noticed CodeLens information is not showing up.

In the preview versions you had to turn this on in the options menu, but I can't seem to find this option anymore.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 9):

You need Visual Studio 2013 **Ultimate** with **Team Foundation Server 2013**.

> To use this feature you will need Visual Studio 2013 Preview and Team
>   Foundation Server 2013 Preview as some information comes from TFS.

and:

> Here's what you’ll need:
>
> - Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 to find references
> - Team Foundation Server 2013 to find changesets, code review requests,
>     and different kinds of work items

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/09/visual-studio-2013-preview-codelens-aka-code-information-indicators.aspx)

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn269218%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) will tell you the same.

You can download Team Foundation Server [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-downloads).

Comment: The VS2013 Ultimate requirement pretty much sucks :/

Comment: You can vote to make it available on other editions: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4150271-make-codelens-available-outside-of-ultimate

Answer (score 7):

The option is hidden in 
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> Code Information Indicators

The only one that appears to work for us is the references, even though all options are enabled.

Update:  My missing options were answered here...
[VS 2013 CodeLens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475761/vs-2013-codelens)

Hope this helps.